# sass :first-child selector not working

Tags: css, compass-sass

I have a element which is in ng-repeat

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <a style="cursor:pointer">
      {{candidateInfo.name}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" class="panel-height" ></div>
</div>
```

I need to increase the height of 1st panel div ;i gave a class="panel-height"

the sass code which i gave is

```
  div .panel-height {
    &:first-child {
        height: 500px;
    }
  }
```

but its not working,no idea where im going wrong

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: which it is the div that want to apply the styles exactly?

Comment: i want to apply css to 
<div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" class="panel-height" ></div>

Comment: I don't know how works `ng-repeat`. If that repeated is all code block you have pasted the css code should be:  `.panel:first:child .panel-height {
    height: 500px;
}`

Comment: i have tried doing this but here i m using sass ,
so i guess i need to use &:first-child 
but this is not working

Comment: In SASS you can use CSS syntax too. If you have to use for some reason `div .panel-height` selector maybe this is helpful for you: `div .panel-height { .panel:first-child &{  height: 500px;  }}`

Comment: Are you trying to style the stop-watch in the FIRST panel heading in the panel parent? I'm a bit confused. Looking at your mark up right now, your selector doesn't really make sense to me.